# 4.6.1 project no longer runs on https://localhost:64674/

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had an old project built on .NET 4.6.1. I distinctly remember running this project on both HTTP and HTTPS previously.

Now, I decided to run it again, and now, it does not run on the https://localhost:64674/ at all.

On FireFox it shows like this

[image]

Other browsers (Edge, Chrome) give something similar. So, it's definitely not a browser issue.

Further, I have definitely enabled SSL everywhere (and I can confirm, from memory, I had the project running on https just fine)

[image]

and also here

[image]

One thing I can think of is...whenever I create a brand new project, I get some sort of a "Accept this Certificate or something". Of course, that only happens on a brand new project.

So, what should I do here to get HTTPS to work?

note 1: if I were to deploy this code, say, on an azure web app, I get HTTPS no problem. So, the code itself is not the issue.

note 2 : on the same computer and visual studio, if I were to create a brand new .net 4.6.1 project, I am able to get https://localhost running.

Comment: Having the same port number for http and https doesn't seem valid. Did you modify either value?

Comment: Thats what I thought as well. However, when I create a new project (note 2), same port for both HTTP and HTTPS. Further, I distinctly remember, back when I was actively using this project, I did not have to use different ports.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? In VS 2019, when I create a new ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.6.1) project, it assigns a different port to the HTTP versus the HTTPS version (and it will start a "site" on both ports when debugging). I don't have an older version installed, or I'd check to see if the tooling has somehow changed.

Comment: One other long-shot suggestion: Visual Studio used to configure IIS Express websites via an applicationhost.config file under your user account (in a folder under something like Documents / IISExpress / config). If you see that file, open it and look for the `<sites>` node under `<system.applicationHost>`. If there is a binding for your site's localhost port there, it might be pointing to an outdated location (or be interfering with the current way VS manages IIS Express).

Comment: @TiesonT. I will check both and update :)

Comment: You can also edit the project file and try manually assigning a different port to the HTTP version. FWIW, this Server Fault question would seem to indicate that's the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/282380/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-error-on-iis-site-was-working-suddenly-stopped#. That, or you need to specify the TLS version so that it uses 1.2 or greater

Comment: I will check and update. as of now, my client and I have decided to ignore the issue and move on with our work as it is not affecting our project in anyway.